# Squash commits on master but separate commits on feature branch?

Tags: git

Let's say Im working on a feature, in a branch called `foo_baz`.

I commit multiple times as I work on the feature.

I periodically push `foo_baz`, a remote-tracking branch, to a remote repo. IE `origin/foo_baz`.

I progress to the point where I want to merge all commits from `foo_baz` into `master` and push to `origin/master`. Here's the question:

Can I merge `foo_baz` into `master` such that all commits are still separate in `foo_baz`'s histroy, but that in `master`'s history, they are all one, squashed commit?

**Edit:**

I'm a bit of a git beginner, so please forgive me if there's something totally obvious that I'm missing. I dug around on the web but couldn't find a direct answer to my question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might indeed be looking for `--squash` (as in the other answers), but you might be looking for `--no-ff` instead.

Here's the difference between the two.  Suppose you start with two commits:

```
A --- B                <-- branch "master", when you start
```

and then make two more on your new branch `foo_baz`:

```
A --- B                <-- master
        \
          C --- D      <-- foo_baz
```

Now (once back on `master`), you have these two options (among others).  You can `git merge --squash foo_baz && git commit` which will give you the following:

```
A --- B ----------- E  <-- master
        \
          C --- D      <-- foo_baz
```

or you can `git merge --no-ff`:

```
A --- B ----------- E  <-- "master" after merge --no-ff
        \         /
          C --- D      <-- foo_baz
```

Both give you a new commit `E`—in the first case, from the separate `git commit` command—but the first one suppresses the multi-parent-ing action, so that in end, when you look back on this a year from now, it looks like you just copied all the changes from the branch.  The *tree* (all the files you get when you `git checkout` the branches) will be the same in both `D` and `E` (in this particular case anyway, where there are no changes to B on `master` before the merge action), but they're different commits.

The difference from a straight `git merge` is that the latter will generally produce a "fast forward", which looks like this:

```
A --- B
        \
          C --- D      <-- foo_baz, master
```

where the angled line can be straightened out, giving you a history where both branches look exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is something like this:

```
git merge --squash foo_baz
git commit
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for the `--squash` flag.